# FullCalendar week/dayview to show only timeslots with events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-5

Anyone have suggestions on how to create a Fullcalendar TimeGridView which would show only times where there are events?

I have a site which shows multiple different google calendars with fullcalendar and in separate tabs. Some calendars have events only 15:00 - 17:00 for example and some have 11:00 - 21:00. I'd like that the minTime and maxTime would set automatically to start time of first event for the day/week and end time of the last event for the day/week. So time slots without events would not be visible at all.

I have done so that I go through the eventsources and find out the first and last time for events for the currently rendered day/week and set those to minTime and maxTime options when initializing the calendar. This works ok for the initial page render, but when user changes a date / week, I would need to update the minTime / maxTime to get it render correctly for the new week / day selection. Otherwise the initial minTime / maxTime would be in use and new events can go beyond those times and not be visible on the calendar.

I can use the events when day is being rendered or events have been fetched to know when date is being changed, but the problem I have is that when I update the minTime / maxTime options in Fullcalendar, the events will be refetched each time and dates are rendered so it will causw infinite loop.

Is there a way to do what I'm asking?

Comment: There'd be no way to do this without forking the timegrid plugin and making a [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js), but that's not a task to undertake lightly. If you just want to save space, have you considered using the list view or daygrid view?

Comment: yea.. those are the options currently what I thought so too.. too bad. I'm hoping this would change in v5 https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4698 ... so I could update minTime and maxTime after events have been loaded.. see https://codepen.io/acerix/pen/NZGpZE?editors=0011

Comment: Let's hope they fix it in v5 then, at least you have an open issue about it. There's time because it's still in beta, and there will be updates after the initial release too. If you have time you could maybe work out how to contribute the fix yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did it like this now, not pretty but works..

1. When I'm creating the calendars, I use google calendar api to get the events from the configured eventsources beforehand for the current visible week. Then loop the events through and find out the start time of the earliest event for the week and end time of the last event for the week.
2. Then when initially creating the calendar, I use the minTime and maxTime options to limit the timegrid to the start time of the first event and to the end time of the last event.
3. Then in viewSkeletonRender event I find the next, back, today, day and week view buttons from UI and add click event handler to the buttons.
4. When next button is clicked for example and timeGridWeek or timeGridDay is in use:

   1. I get the start and end time for the view from calendar.view.activeStart and calendar.view.activeEnd
   2. Then get from google calendar api the events for that range and find out the start and end times for the fist and last event for that week
   3. Then use the calendar.setOption to set new minTime and maxTime
   4. Then call calendar.destroy and calendar.render to get it render new time grid with updated min and max time

This works, but of course there are quite a lot of unnecessary calls to the google calendar api in this solution... in initial calendar creation I first query the events, then FullCalendar queries the events.. then when week is changed, I query the events for next week, FullCalendar queries the events for next week, update min/maxTime options, which causes FullCalendar to re-query the events again couple times I think, then I destroy and render and the events are queried again by FullCalendar I think. But... it looks ok for end user :D

Would be best for me to at least implement some function to keep cache for the queried events and return from cache if event for requested range has already been queried from google calendar api.